# Deleting geodatabases that are more than one week old

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, esri-geodatabase

I am using ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 and Python 2.6.6 and am trying to make an update script to copy the geodatabase to a backup folder with the date as part of the name, got that to work.

Then export features from my editing geodatabase to the one on our server, got that working.

But now I want to, at the end of my script, to go back to the backup folder and delete any geodatabases there that are older than 1 week to keep it clean.

Tried a number of ways but they didn't work, any suggestions?

```
import re
import os
import datetime
import time
import sys

from subprocess import call

now = time.time()
cutoff = now - (7 * 86400)

files = os.listdir("C:\GIS Info\Test\Backup")
for xfile in files:
        if os.path.isfile( "C:\GIS Info\Test\Backup" + xfile ):
                t = os.stat( "C:\GIS Info\Test\Backup" + xfile )
                c = t.st_ctime

                # delete file if older than a week
                if c < cutoff:
                        os.remove("C:\GIS Info\Test\Backup" + xfile)
```

This is the code I was trying to use that got me the furthest.

Comment: Are you wanting the update script to be in python, or would shell command work as well?

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Were you unable to delete or unable to filter to the correct geodatabases?

Comment: for delete: arcpy.Delete_management(full_path), for last access time see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16464228/python-get-last-reading-time-of-a-file

Comment: Can you include a code snippet of how you are trying to "go back to the backup folder and delete any geodatabases there that are older than 1 week", please?  No need to show us all the ways that you have tried, just the one that you thought should have been the most likely to work.  Also include any error messages thrown by running that code snippet.  Also, what type(s) of geodatabases are you trying to delete?

Comment: how are you determining that GDBs are older than one week? Are you using the file system time, as @MichaelMiles-Stimson is suggesting, or using the GDB name itself (you mention that the date is part of the file name)?

Comment: Good point @StephenLead. Filenames would be easier but if you don't trust that they're genuinely not needed by filename then if the file has not been accessed in that time that would show that they are truly not needed... note: virus checking etc. may affect the result, it's possible that the Geodatabases are periodically scanned which means they're never a week old.

Comment: I added the code to my original post. It did not return any errors just didn't delete, I think it is because the file geodatabase is more like a directory than a file. It doesn't matter if I use the file name or the time stamp, the only example I found, that I understood, was the time stamp method so I used that. I am using arcpy in other parts of the script but I didn't think I needed to for the delete, should I be using arcpy.Delete_management instead?
I usually build these as models, export to python, combine, then make a tool that runs all the processes I want to run, iterations stump me.

Comment: I have been using this script for the past few months. Works great! However, when it comes to Python scripting, my skills are weak. How would I change this script to only delete gdb's by date in the root directory? Something like this? "
If you only want to remove files in a directory it can be a oneliner from pathlib import Path [f.unlink() for f in Path("/path/to/folder").glob("*") if f.is_file()]
"
(Cited: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/185936/how-to-delete-the-contents-of-a-folder) Thank you for your response(s) in advance, -SJE

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since FGDB's are treated as folders, this script looks for folders in a directory older that seven days, then uses the Delete management tool to remove the old folders.

```
import os
import time
import arcpy

dirPath = r"C:\test_data"
cutoff =  7 * 86400
present = time.time()
directories = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dirPath, topdown=False):
    for name in dirs:
        subDirPath = os.path.join(root, name)
        if (present - os.path.getmtime(subDirPath)) > cutoff:
            directories.append(subDirPath)

for gdb in directories:
    arcpy.Delete_management(gdb)
```

It doesn't work only on GDB's, it deletes all sub directories older that seven days. But you could tweak it to only delete GDB's and leave other directories in place.

Comment: That's got it, thanks. Don't think there will be an issue with other directories Backup should only hold the backedup databases.